# I can't fill svg icon info

Tags: svg

sorry for this simple question, but i can't fill the content of this svg, always stay blank. How should i do?

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none">
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M8.00039 3.39999C5.45988 3.39999 3.40039 5.45948 3.40039 7.99999C3.40039 10.5405 5.45988 12.6 8.00039 12.6C10.5409 12.6 12.6004 10.5405 12.6004 7.99999C12.6004 5.45948 10.5409 3.39999 8.00039 3.39999ZM1.40039 7.99999C1.40039 4.35491 4.35531 1.39999 8.00039 1.39999C11.6455 1.39999 14.6004 4.35491 14.6004 7.99999C14.6004 11.6451 11.6455 14.6 8.00039 14.6C4.35531 14.6 1.40039 11.6451 1.40039 7.99999ZM8.00039 4.19999C8.55268 4.19999 9.00039 4.64771 9.00039 5.19999V5.23999C9.00039 5.79228 8.55268 6.23999 8.00039 6.23999C7.44811 6.23999 7.00039 5.79228 7.00039 5.23999V5.19999C7.00039 4.64771 7.44811 4.19999 8.00039 4.19999ZM7.00039 6.84062V10.8406H9.00039V6.84062H7.00039Z" fill="#252B2E"/>
</svg>
```

Thanks

expected result: fill the inside of the icon with a color

Comment: If you need to fill the shape you can use another path placed before the actual one. For example you can copy the first part of the d attribute from the first M command to the first Z command and use it to generate the "fill" path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those lines are not single-path strokes, they are actually already filled shapes with no-color strokes, so changing the fill just changes the "line" color (which is actually a fill). You can see this clearly if you zoom in and add a stroke.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="460" height="460" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="none">
<path d="M8.00039 3.39999C5.45988 3.39999 3.40039 5.45948 3.40039 7.99999C3.40039 10.5405 5.45988 12.6 8.00039 12.6C10.5409 12.6 12.6004 10.5405 12.6004 7.99999C12.6004 5.45948 10.5409 3.39999 8.00039 3.39999ZM1.40039 7.99999C1.40039 4.35491 4.35531 1.39999 8.00039 1.39999C11.6455 1.39999 14.6004 4.35491 14.6004 7.99999C14.6004 11.6451 11.6455 14.6 8.00039 14.6C4.35531 14.6 1.40039 11.6451 1.40039 7.99999ZM8.00039 4.19999C8.55268 4.19999 9.00039 4.64771 9.00039 5.19999V5.23999C9.00039 5.79228 8.55268 6.23999 8.00039 6.23999C7.44811 6.23999 7.00039 5.79228 7.00039 5.23999V5.19999C7.00039 4.64771 7.44811 4.19999 8.00039 4.19999ZM7.00039 6.84062V10.8406H9.00039V6.84062H7.00039Z" fill="blue" stroke="red" stroke-width="1" />
</svg>
```

If you want to "fill" this without changing the path definition (which is the right way to do this) - you should draw a circle with your desired fill first at the same location and then draw the icon over it. You could also do a filter to do this, but it would be a hassle.

Comment: where should I draw the circle to get the fastest result? sorry if I ask trivial questions, I'm not very practical in writing svg? thanks

Comment: Take an hour and watch an "intro to SVG" youtube - it will save you a lot of time if you're going to work with it -> circle cy="8" cx="8" r="6" fill="red"

Comment: okay, thanks for the advice. As soon as I can I'll also do a test and then I'll give you feedback. Thanks for your time